# Unity Attribute Interception with ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, unity-container, aop

I'm trying to use Unity to apply a call handler via an attribute against my ApiController method, but the call handler is never invoked.

Attribute:

```
public class LogAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    private readonly int _order;

    public LogAttribute(int order)
    {
        _order = order;
    }

    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return new LoggingCallHandler
        { 
            Order = _order
        };
    }
}
```

The call handler:

```
  public class LoggingCallHandler : ICallHandler
    {
        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
        {
          //.....stuff   
        }
    }
```

Registration:

```
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
container.RegisterType<IMyApiController>();
container.Configure<Interception>()
     .SetInterceptorFor<IMyApiController>(new InterfaceInterceptor());
```

Dependency Resolver (using WebActiviatorEx):

```
public static class UnityWebApiActivator
{
    public static void Start() 
    {            
        var resolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer());

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you applying the `LogAttribute` ?

Comment: Just on a ApiController method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web API system will use the dependency resolver to resolve the controller class (e.g. `MyApiController`), not the interface that such controller class implements (e.g. `IMyApiController`). I don't know of a way to make the Web API system request the interface instead (and I doubt that there is a way to do that).

One solution is to intercept the controller it self (`MyApiController`) but since it is a class, you cannot use the interface interceptor (`InterfaceInterceptor`) and instead you have to use the virtual method interceptor like this:

```
container.Configure<Interception>()
     .SetInterceptorFor<MyApiController>(new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
```

This will require that you make the action methods that you want to intercept `virtual`.

Please note that you can still intercept other dependencies injected to your controllers (that are defined as interfaces) via `InterfaceInterceptor`. This is because the Web API system will ask the container to resolve them as interfaces, not as classes.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense & works. Bit of a shame you have to make the methods virtual, but I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: You welcome. You might want to search to see if there is a way to force the Web API framework to ask for `IMyApiController` instead of `MyApiController`. My intuition is telling me there probably isn't, though.